# MVC Ajax request on click of textbox?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, ajax

Im using MVC2, im trying to basically fire an ajax request. Im basically trying to get a specific partial view to load in a div when the user selects a textbox.

(to provide background.. the textboxes are for users to input measurements, i have a div that contains a partial view that returns instructions on how to measure. id like them to load when the user clicks on the the textbox to input their measurements)

Is this possible? ive used ajax.actionlink's elcewhere in my site, but im not too sure on what to research.. as im reasonably sure ajax.actionlinks wont be the tool that i need for this job.

Ive been attempting to mess around with something like this

```
$(function() {
$('#Chest').focus(function () {
$('#measureRight').load('@Url.Action("http://www.google.com")');
});
});
```

(in the above example 'Chest' is a textbox id and www.google.com is just to check that a request is being fired)

any advice would be appriciated. im terribly new / totally new to jquery, so please be kind!

Thanks

Comment: sorry im not too sure what that means?

Comment: It means you can't send a request to Google.com

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: ahh ok, think ive got the basic understanding of why i cant use google.com, ive replaced it with my partial view. still no luck. thanks for you response.

Comment: You could do it server-side, then the SOP doesnt apply. So you do an AJAX request to your server, which then goes the GET to Google via a web request and returns the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if jQuery works differently in a MVC or ASP environment but this should work:

```
<input type="text" id="myField" />
<div style="display:none" id="myDiv"></div>

$(function() {

   $('#myField').focus(function() {

      $('#myDiv').load('/path/to/other/page').show();

   });

});
```

Whatever you have on this page '/path/to/other/page' will load inside your div. If you want to load only a portion of that page, then you can pass a second parameter (not sure if that's the right word in this case) identifying the element you want to grab content from, i.e. the id or class of the element on that page that you want to show like so:

```
$('#myDiv').load('/path/to/other/page #showOnlyWhatsInHere');
```